# button is not appearing after editing it, qml, qt quick2

Tags: qt, button, qml

I have trouble

buttons are not appearing after editing. Button looses its property right after going to code.

```
Button {

    id: edit
    x: 374
    y: 385
    width: 132
    height: 60
    text: qsTr("edit")
    highlighted: false
    flat: false
    down: false
    checked: false
    autoRepeat: false
    autoExclusive: false
    hoverEnabled: false
    checkable: false
    activeFocusOnTab: true
    bottomPadding: 0.1
    onClicked: fileDialog.open()
}
```

Comment: Please describe how you instantiate it. Which version of the `Button` are you using? From `QtQuick.Control 2.x` or `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`? Please describe the exact steps to reproduce your problem, including the full (but minimal) code necessary to do so.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help us understand what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score -2):

i see error in your code

line

```
onClicked: fileDialog.open()
```

should look like this

```
onClicked:{ fileDialog.open()}
```

like it is done here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html

Comment: In QML both options are adequate.

Comment: @eyllanesc i am not sure about that since onClicked is reaction to signal clicked and not a parameter

Comment: Try it out and you'll notice that both codes work. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks i just recaled  that  it should be wraped in {}

maybe it was problem when onClicked vould react to multiple things